# Using simple weights (-1, -1) and bias (2) for NAND perceptron

Tags: math, neural-network, perceptron

In most study material about perceptrons, a perceptron is defined like this.

output = 1 if w . x + b > 0
output = 0 if w . x + b <= 0

(The dot '.' in the above formulas represent the dot product.)

In most examples of NAND perceptron I have seen, the NAND perceptron is
defined like these:

- w = [-2, -2], b = 3 (source: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)
- w = [-1, -1], b = 1.5 (source: http://users.monash.edu/~app/CSE5301/Lnts/LbD.pdf)
- w = [-0.6, -0.6], b = 1 (source: http://toritris.weebly.com/perceptron-2-logical-operations.html)

I am defining my NAND perceptron as follows.

- w = [-1, -1], b = 2

Here is the proof that it works like a NAND perceptron.

```
x0 x1 | w0 * x0 + w1 * x1 + b | output
------+-----------------------+-------
0  0  | 2                     | 1
0  1  | 1                     | 1
1  0  | 1                     | 1
1  1  | 0                     | 0
```

It this a valid NAND perceptron? Is there any specific reason why existing text do not use a simple NAND perceptron like this?

Comment: All of the weights you listed above work (the 3 you linked and your own as well). All of the weights you listed seem pretty simple to me, as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is not a good practice to draw the discriminative boundary near the sample data:[image]

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Having the discriminative boundary on the sample data makes it necessary that `output = 1 if w . x + b > 0; output = 0 if w . x + b <= 0`, i.e. the 0 output must be defined by non-strict equality. But with the other perceptrons where the discriminative boundary is not on the sample, any definition of the perceptron both `output = 1 if w . x + b > 0; output = 0 if w . x + b <= 0` and `output = 1 if w . x + b >= 0; output = 0 if w . x + b < 0` would work. It doesn't matter where we put the non-strict equality.